# WPF ObservableCollection<T> of UI Framework Element Nested 2 Classes deep

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I have created a custom FrameWorkElement ( Battery.cs ) to represent the data to the user in the UI. Within the Battery.cs class I had several dependencyProperties so the UI could monitor the various changes and re-render the object upon changes.

I placed that ObservableCollection within my MainWindowViewModel.cs, which was bound to the main view through a ListBox.

Everything was working properly however this was only for testing as I needed to move the collection down into another class which was going to manage / update the batteries. This management was going to happen asynchronously and thus I was running into a lot of problems with the DependencyProperties calls within the Battery.cs class as they were on the UI thread and not the management/process thread.

So I removed the DependencyProperties, and tried to move the DependencyProperty up to the MainWindowViewModel.cs. Now I am not getting errors about which thread has ownership and I can see that the Batteries in the ObservableCollection are being updated. However the OnRender method is never being called by the UI. So the Batteries are never being rendered/shown anymore.

Here is the code for the DependencyProperty in the MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty batteriesProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Batteries",
            typeof(ObservableCollection<Battery>), 
            typeof(MainWindow),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Battery>()));

        public ObservableCollection<Battery> Batteries
        {
            get { return tbModel.Modules[0].batteries; }
        }
```

I think my main problem may be in this line

```
            new UIPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<Battery>()));
```

However I can't seem to figure out what it should be, or how to adjust the code such that the UI does update the graphics once I have called InvalidateVisual within the Battery.cs class.

```
public void UpdatePacket(Packet packet)
        {
            packet= packet;
            Voltage = packet.Voltage;
            InvalidateVisual();
        }
```

The InvalidateVisual() method is executing however the OnRender override is never being executed.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I misunderstood your explanation.
Are you writing that batteriesProperty is a member of the ViewModel?
And, accordingly, you pass the ViewModel to the DataContext property of the FrameWorkElement?
If so, then the ViewModel is not part of the Visual Tree. Therefore, calling InvalidateVisual () in the ViewModel does not in any way affect the visual tree and, accordingly, the OnRender () method will not be called.

Comment: No InvalidateVisual() is called on the FrameworkElement class. The dependency property shown was written in the ViewModel so that we didn't have threading conflicts. When I had the dependency property in the Battery.cs class and the ObservableCollection in the ViewModel then everything was working fine. However once I started threading and moving the ObservableCollection down to where I actually needed it in model is when I started having issues.

Answer (score 0):

1. Making ViewModel derived from DependecyObject is pointless. This only complicates and confuses the implementation.
2. The Batteries property of type ObservableCollection must be a regular CLR read-only property in the ViewModel.

```cs
    public ObservableCollection<Battery>() Batteries {get;}
        = new ObservableCollection<Battery>();
```

3. If an instance of the ViewModel exists in the entire session of the Application, then in the ViewModel constructor, synchronize the bindings to this collection.

```cs
        protected static readonly Dispatcher Dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Batteries, ((ICollection)Batteries).SyncRoot);
            }
            else
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(Batteries, ((ICollection)Batteries).SyncRoot));
            }

            // Some Code
        }
```

4. If the instances of the ViewModel can be destroyed, replace each other, then the synchronization of the bindings retains a reference to the instance of the ViewModel and therefore this instance will not be deleted by the GC. Also, the synchronization of bindings does not always provide thread safety for working with a collection.
   In these cases, you are not using BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization ().
   But instead, you always work with the collection only in the Dispatcher thread.

```cs
        protected static readonly Dispatcher Dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            // Some Code
        } 

        ... SomeMethod(...) 
        {
            // Some Code

            if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
            {
                Batteries.Add(...);
            }
            else
            {
                Dispatcher.Invoke(()=>Batteries.Add(...));
                // Or
                Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(()=>Batteries.Add(...));
            }


            // Some Code
        }
```

Comment: Well this did help in that now I can see why my rendering wasn't happening. However I still have issues of which thread has ownership of the object. I am getting 

```System.InvalidOperationException: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.```

Comment: The details you provided are not sufficient to determine the cause of the problem.
Try to make a minimal project that demonstrates this problem.
And provide it (via GitHub) for research.

Comment: You don't need to determine which thread is performing the action.
You only need to determine whether it is the Dispatcher thread or not.
To check, use the `Dispatcher.CheckAccess()` method.
If it returns true, perform actions on the current thread.
If false, then marshal the actions to the Dispatcher thread.